# Prevent ImageView redraw state after hide keyboard

Tags: android, android-imageview

First, I have a view like this:

[image]

When user press some text in edittext, I try to draw some rectangles in ImageView with specific coordinates. The problem is when the soft keyboard is hidden, all draw state of Imageview display **wrong coordinates**, look like it invalidated the imageview. I wonder is there any way to stop this.
Here is my Custom Drawable Imageview:

```
public class DrawableImageView extends ImageView {
private Paint ptBlur;
private List<Rect> rects;
private int originWidth;
private int originHeight;

public DrawableImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initPaint();
}

public DrawableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initPaint();
}

public DrawableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initPaint();
}

public void setRects(List<Rect> rects, int originWidth, int originHeight) {
    this.originHeight = originHeight;
    this.originWidth = originWidth;
    this.rects = rects;
    invalidate();
}

private void initPaint() {
    ptBlur = new Paint();
    ptBlur.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    ptBlur.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    ptBlur.setStrokeWidth(5);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (rects != null) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        for (Rect rect : rects) {
            rect.bottom = Math.round(height * rect.bottom / originHeight);
            rect.left = Math.round(width * rect.left / originWidth);
            rect.right = Math.round(width * rect.right / originWidth);
            rect.top = Math.round(height * rect.top / originHeight);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, ptBlur);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The `OnEditorActionListener` for EditText:

```
  // get the rectangles and draw 
  List<Rect> rects = DataUtil.getHighlightRectList(searchText);
  drawableImageView.setRects(rects, pageWidth, pageHeight);
```